# Best place for index call when using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, solr

currently i'm thinking on where's the best place in my code where i must put the call method to my indexing services (solR).

The fact is that i must assure that every entity which is stored in the db is indexed,  i'm using hibernate and i will try to implement it with interceptors.

Any advice | idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have placed the call at hibernate's entity interceptor. As only  one

EntityInterceptor is allowed, we implement the filterchain pattern to pass the entity

across many Interceptors.

Hope it helps someone ...